# How to search text in oracle view

Tags: oracle, query, oracle-12c, view

I need to create a filter where I can locate specific text in my views.

I tried using the following queries:

```
SELECT OWNER,
       VIEW_NAME
FROM DBA_VIEWS
WHERE UPPER(TEXT) LIKE UPPER('%ABC%');
```

But the following error is returned:

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got LONG

I also tried using DBA_SOURCE and DBA_DEPENDENCIES, but I didn't get the expected result.

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM ALL_SOURCE a
 where UPPER(A.TEXT) like UPPER('%ABC%');
```

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
  DBA_DEPENDENCIES
WHERE
  TYPE = 'VIEW'
      AND REFERENCED_NAME NOT IN ('DBMS_STANDARD','STANDARD')
ORDER BY
  OWNER;
```

Is there something similar I can use to collect this information?

Comment: What do you want to find in the view text? A table name, a column name, a string constant?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option: create **table** which selects data from `user_views`, converting `long` to `clob` - then query that table.

Sample view:

```
SQL> create or replace view v_emp as
  2    select empno, deptno, ename, job, sal
  3    from emp
  4    where deptno in (10, 20)
  5      and sal >= 1000;

View created.
```

Paul (in his comment) asked what's wrong with `all_source`; it doesn't contain views:

```
SQL> select distinct type from user_source;

TYPE
------------
PROCEDURE
PACKAGE
PACKAGE BODY
FUNCTION
```

This is what you tried:

```
SQL> select * from user_views where instr(text, 'deptno') > 0;
select * from user_views where instr(text, 'deptno') > 0
                                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got LONG
```

This is what I suggested:

```
SQL> create table my_views as
  2  select view_name, to_lob(text) text from user_views;

Table created.

SQL> desc my_views
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 VIEW_NAME                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 TEXT                                               CLOB
```

Finally, query:

```
SQL> select * from my_views
  2  where instr(text, 'deptno') > 0;

VIEW_NAME
------------------------------
TEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
V_EMP
select empno, deptno, ename, job, sal
  from emp
  where deptno in (10, 20)


    
SQL> drop table my_views;

Table dropped.

SQL>
```

Obvious drawback is that you have to create such a table every time you want to find something.

If you hoped that CTE solves that problem, nope - it doesn't:

```
SQL> with my_views as
  2    (select view_name, to_lob(text) text from user_views)
  3  select * from my_views
  4  where instr(text, 'deptno') > 0;
select * from my_views
       *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got LONG


SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks Littlefoot, I commented too quickly and was thinking of triggers (which are presented as longs but can also be found in source), not views. I added my solution for views.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to often search views, you can create a view+function wrapper around `dba_views` that transforms the `text` column into a `clob` which you can then search. This will avoid having to use CTAS to create unnecessary one-off physical data segments that are immediately stale:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE dba_views_rectype IS OBJECT (
TEXT_LENGTH NUMBER,
TEXT    CLOB,
TEXT_VC VARCHAR2(4000),
TYPE_TEXT_LENGTH    NUMBER,
TYPE_TEXT   VARCHAR2(4000),
OID_TEXT_LENGTH NUMBER,
OID_TEXT    VARCHAR2(4000),
VIEW_TYPE_OWNER VARCHAR2(128),
VIEW_TYPE   VARCHAR2(128),
SUPERVIEW_NAME  VARCHAR2(128),
EDITIONING_VIEW VARCHAR2(1),
READ_ONLY   VARCHAR2(1),
CONTAINER_DATA  VARCHAR2(1),
BEQUEATH    VARCHAR2(12),
ORIGIN_CON_ID   NUMBER,
DEFAULT_COLLATION   VARCHAR2(100),
CONTAINERS_DEFAULT  VARCHAR2(3),
CONTAINER_MAP   VARCHAR2(3),
EXTENDED_DATA_LINK  VARCHAR2(3),
EXTENDED_DATA_LINK_MAP  VARCHAR2(3),
HAS_SENSITIVE_COLUMN    VARCHAR2(3),
ADMIT_NULL  VARCHAR2(3),
PDB_LOCAL_ONLY  VARCHAR2(3))
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE dba_views_tabtype IS TABLE OF dba_views_rectype
/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_dba_views_ext (in_owner IN varchar2, in_view_name IN varchar2)
  RETURN dba_views_tabtype PIPELINED
AS  
  var_cursor binary_integer;
  var_query varchar2(4000);
  res pls_integer;
  tab_desc dbms_sql.desc_tab;
  var_column_count pls_integer;
  rec_dummy_view dba_views_rectype;
  var_owner dba_views.owner%TYPE;
  var_view_name dba_views.view_name%TYPE;
  var_version_1 integer;
BEGIN
  SELECT SUBSTR(version,1,INSTR(version,'.')-1)
    INTO var_version_1
    FROM v$instance;
  
  var_query := 'SELECT *
                  FROM dba_views
                 WHERE owner = :owner
                   AND view_name = :view_name';
                   
  var_cursor := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
  dbms_sql.parse(var_cursor,var_query,dbms_sql.native);
  dbms_sql.bind_variable(var_cursor,'owner',in_owner);
  dbms_sql.bind_variable(var_cursor,'view_name',in_view_name);
  
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,1,var_owner,128);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,2,var_view_name,128);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,3,rec_dummy_view.text_length);
  dbms_sql.define_column_long(var_cursor,4);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,5,rec_dummy_view.text_vc,4000);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,6,rec_dummy_view.type_text_length);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,7,rec_dummy_view.type_text,4000);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,8,rec_dummy_view.oid_text_length);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,9,rec_dummy_view.oid_text,4000);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,10,rec_dummy_view.view_type_owner,128);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,11,rec_dummy_view.view_type,128);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,12,rec_dummy_view.superview_name,128);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,13,rec_dummy_view.editioning_view,1);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,14,rec_dummy_view.read_only,1);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,15,rec_dummy_view.container_data,1);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,16,rec_dummy_view.bequeath,12);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,17,rec_dummy_view.origin_con_id);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,18,rec_dummy_view.default_collation,100);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,19,rec_dummy_view.containers_default,3);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,20,rec_dummy_view.container_map,3);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,21,rec_dummy_view.extended_data_link,3);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,22,rec_dummy_view.extended_data_link_map,3);
  dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,23,rec_dummy_view.has_sensitive_column,3);
  
  IF var_version_1 >= 19
  THEN
    dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,24,rec_dummy_view.admit_null,3);
    dbms_sql.define_column(var_cursor,25,rec_dummy_view.pdb_local_only,3);
  END IF;
  
  res := dbms_sql.execute(var_cursor);
  
  WHILE dbms_sql.fetch_rows(var_cursor) > 0
  LOOP
    DECLARE
      var_text_clob clob;
      var_offset pls_integer := 0;
      var_buffer_length pls_integer := 32760;
      var_value_length pls_integer := 0;
      var_long_piece long;
      rec_view dba_views_rectype := dba_views_rectype(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    BEGIN
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,3,rec_view.text_length);
              
      dbms_lob.createtemporary(var_text_clob, false, dbms_lob.call);
        
      LOOP
        dbms_sql.column_value_long(c => var_cursor,
                                   position => 4,
                                   length => var_buffer_length,
                                   offset => var_offset,
                                   value => var_long_piece,
                                   value_length => var_value_length);
                                   
        EXIT WHEN var_value_length = 0;
        
        dbms_lob.append(var_text_clob, var_long_piece);
        var_offset := var_offset + var_value_length;
      END LOOP;
      
      rec_view.text := var_text_clob;
      
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,5,rec_view.text_vc);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,6,rec_view.type_text_length);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,7,rec_view.type_text);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,8,rec_view.oid_text_length);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,9,rec_view.oid_text);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,10,rec_view.view_type_owner);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,11,rec_view.view_type);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,12,rec_view.superview_name);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,13,rec_view.editioning_view);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,14,rec_view.read_only);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,15,rec_view.container_data);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,16,rec_view.bequeath);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,17,rec_view.origin_con_id);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,18,rec_view.default_collation);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,19,rec_view.containers_default);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,20,rec_view.container_map);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,21,rec_view.extended_data_link);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,22,rec_view.extended_data_link_map);
      dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,23,rec_view.has_sensitive_column);
      
      IF var_version_1 >= 19
      THEN
        dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,24,rec_view.admit_null);
        dbms_sql.column_value(var_cursor,25,rec_view.pdb_local_only);
      END IF;
      
      PIPE ROW(rec_view);
    END;
  END LOOP;

  dbms_sql.close_cursor(var_cursor);
  
  RETURN;
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF dbms_sql.is_open(var_cursor)
    THEN
      dbms_sql.close_cursor(var_cursor);
    END IF;
    
    RAISE;
END;
/
  
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dba_views_ext
AS
SELECT v.owner,
       v.view_name,
       x.*
  FROM dba_views v
       CROSS APPLY TABLE(f_dba_views_ext(v.owner,v.view_name)) x
 ORDER BY owner,view_name
/
```

That's a one-time setup. From then on, you simply query whenever needed:

```
SELECT *
  FROM dba_views_ext
 WHERE UPPER(text) LIKE '%ABC%'
```

A DBA can make this available to everyone by creating `all_views_ext` and `user_views_ext`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW all_views_ext
AS
SELECT v.owner,
       v.view_name,
       x.*
  FROM all_views v
       CROSS APPLY TABLE(f_dba_views_ext(v.owner,v.view_name)) x
 ORDER BY owner,view_name
/
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW user_views_ext
AS
SELECT USER owner,
       v.view_name,
       x.*
  FROM user_views v
       CROSS APPLY TABLE(f_dba_views_ext(USER,v.view_name)) x
 ORDER BY view_name
/

GRANT select ON dbatools.DBA_VIEWS_EXT TO select_catalog_role;
GRANT select ON dbatools.ALL_VIEWS_EXT TO public;
GRANT select ON dbatools.USER_VIEWS_EXT TO public;
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM DBA_VIEWS_EXT FOR dbatools.DBA_VIEWS_EXT;
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM ALL_VIEWS_EXT FOR dbatools.ALL_VIEWS_EXT;
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM USER_VIEWS_EXT FOR dbatools.USER_VIEWS_EXT;
```